# How to exclude multiple values in OData call?

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap

I am creating a SAPUI5 application. This application is connected to a backend SAP system via OData. In the SAPUI5 application I use a smart chart control. Out of the box the smart chart lets the user create filters for the underlying data. This works fine - except if you try to use multiple 'not equals' for one property. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I found out that all properties within an 'and_expression' (including nested or_expressions) must have unique name.

> The reason why two parameters with the same property don't get parsed into the select options:
>
> `/IWCOR/CL_ODATA_EXPR_UTILS=>GET_FILTER_SELECT_OPTIONS` takes the expression you pass and parses it into a table of select options.
>
> The select option table returned is of type `/IWCOR/IF_ODATA_TYPES=>EDM_SELECT_OPTION_T` which is a `HASHED TABLE  ..  WITH UNIQUE KEY` property.

<sup>From: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3170195</sup>

The problem is that you cannot combine `NE` terms with `OR`. Because both parameters after the `NE` should not be shown in the result set.

So at the end the `it_filter_select_options` is empty and only the `iv_filter_string` is filled.

Is there a manual way of facing this problem (evaluation of the `iv_filter_string`) to handle multiple `NE` terms?

This would be an example request:

```
XYZ/SmartChartSet?$filter=(Category%20ne%20%27Smartphone%27%20and%20Category%20ne%20%27Notebook%27)%20and%20Purchaser%20eq%20%27CompanyABC%27%20and%20BuyDate%20eq%20datetime%272018-10-12T02%3a00%3a00%27&$inlinecount=allpages
```

Normally I want this to exclude items with the category 'Notebook' and 'Smartphone' from my result set that I retrieve from the backend.

Comment: Can you share the client side piece of code that builds the filter?

Comment: The separation of the request into the filters (it_filter_select_options) is not modified by me. It is a standard sap gw functionality (methods) - not sure where this is done. Later you can access the filter table inside the DPC  EXT methods.

Comment: OK. You said "the smart chart let the user create filters". How is this done?

Comment: [link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartchart.general/preview)   - when using the smart chart, out of the box you have a settings button. If you press it you are able to do some sortings and filter stuff. What is sortable and filterable comes from the metadata. The metadata is created out of the service that was created in the transaction SEGW.

Comment: Also, You said "you cannot combine 'NE' terms with 'OR'". The query is: `(Category ne 'Smartphone' and Category ne 'Notebook') and Purchaser eq 'CompanyABC' and BuyDate eq datetime'2018-10-12T02:00:00'`. Also the variable names you mentioned are confusing. `/iwcor/cl_odata_expr_utils=>get_filter_select_options` receives `iv_expression` and returns `rt_select_options`. I am posting a possible answer now. fix me if i didn't get you.

Comment: This would be valid: ` "Category ne 'Smartphone' or Category ne 'Notebook'" `. But this is not what I want because both 'NE' terms have to be combined. But when it is combined with 'AND' it causes problems - > as mentioned the select option table returned is of type /IWCOR/IF_ODATA_TYPES=>EDM_SELECT_OPTION_T which is a HASHED TABLE  ..  WITH UNIQUE KEY property.

Comment: What would be valid? The query in your question is with `and` operator, which is reasonable. What do you mean by 'combined'? `Range Table` is a set of signs, operators and values.

Comment: Sorry it is hard to describe what I wanted to say. F.ex. When you are setting up two 'EQ' filters for one property (category) -> it is automatically transformed into: Category eq 'ABC' OR Category eq 'ABC'. But in the case of multiple 'NE' you cannot use 'OR'. (You have to use 'AND' -> and this leads to this issue)

Comment: just pure boolean try, what about `not( Category eq 'Smartphone' or Category eq 'Notebook' ) and ...` ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If the smart control allows you to enter that condition, the server should be able to correctly process it. If that's not the case, you should create a ticket with SAP's support.

Comment: @Florian Agreed. The filter `(Category ne 'Smartphone' and Category ne 'Notebook') and Purchaser eq 'CompanyABC' and BuyDate eq datetime'2018-10-12T02:00:00'` is equivalent to `not ( Category eq 'Smartphone' or Category eq 'Notebook' ) and Purchaser eq 'CompanyABC' and BuyDate eq datetime'2018-10-12T02:00:00'`, so it can be stored in a SELECT-OPTIONS `{ Category, [{E EQ Smartphone},{E EQ Notebook}] },{ Purchaser, [{I EQ CompanyABC}] },{ BuyDate, [{I EQ 20181012020000}] }` so the code could be improved to be more tolerant. But maybe E(xclusions) are not handled by the standard (?)

Comment: Yes, might be those things are on a not-supported list. But if that’s the case, the smart control shouldn’t offer these options in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a bug inside `/iwcor/cl_odata_expr_utils=>get_filter_select_options` which makes it unable to treat multiple `NE` filters of the same component, and you cannot wait for an OSS. I would suggest to wrap it inside a new static method that will make the following logic (if you will be stuck with the ABAP implementation i would try to at least partially implement it when i get time):

1. Get all instances of `<COMPONENT> ne '<VALUE>'` inside a `()` (using REGEX).
2. Replace each `<COMPONENT>` with `<COMPONENT>_<i>` so there will be ( `<COMPONENT>_1 ne '<VALUE_1>' and <COMPONENT>_2 ne '<VALUE_2>' and... <COMPONENT>_<n> ne '<VALUE_n>'` ).
3. Call `/iwcor/cl_odata_expr_utils=>get_filter_select_options` with the modified query.
4. Modify the `rt_select_options` result by changing `COMPONENT_<i>` to `<COMPONENT>` again.

Comment: Hi Dorad, I tried what you described, but it ends up in this error: cx_no_check.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the source but I recall that multiple "ne" isn't supported. Isn't that the same thing that happens when you do multiple negatives in SE16, some warning is displayed?

I found this extract for Business ByDesign:

> Excluding two values using the OR operator (for example: $filter=CACCDOCTYPE ne ‘1000’ or CACCDOCTYPE ne ‘4000’) is not possible.

The workaround I see is to select the Categories you actively want, not the ones you don't in the UI5 app.

I can also confirm that my code snippet I've used a long time for filtering also has the same problem...

```html
* <SIGNATURE>---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
* | Instance Public Method ZCL_MGW_ABS_DATA->FILTERING
* +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
* | [--->] IO_TECH_REQUEST_CONTEXT        TYPE REF TO /IWBEP/IF_MGW_REQ_ENTITYSET
* | [<-->] CR_ENTITYSET                   TYPE REF TO DATA
* | [!CX!] /IWBEP/CX_MGW_BUSI_EXCEPTION
* | [!CX!] /IWBEP/CX_MGW_TECH_EXCEPTION
* +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</SIGNATURE>
METHOD FILTERING.

  FIELD-SYMBOLS <lt_entityset> TYPE STANDARD TABLE.
  ASSIGN cr_entityset->* TO <lt_entityset>.

  CHECK: cr_entityset   IS BOUND,
         <lt_entityset> IS ASSIGNED.

  DATA(lo_filter) = io_tech_request_context->get_filter( ).

  /iwbep/cl_mgw_data_util=>filtering(
    exporting it_select_options = lo_filter->get_filter_select_options( )
    changing  ct_data           = <lt_entityset> ).

ENDMETHOD.
```

Comment: Hey, the thing is the 'excluding' functionality is sth. that comes out of the box of the smart chart control. So the call is automatically triggered in this form with multiple 'NE'. Your idea of selecting only what is wanted and not what is not wanted seems to be good. But the problem is that I can't do getEntity requests for every record I want.

Comment: I see. A positive filter like this should work:

XYZ/SmartChartSet?$filter=(Category eq 'Laptop' or Category eq 'Watch') and Purchaser eq 'CompanyABC'